# How to refer to parent object from a child method, in ES6?

Tags: object, ecmascript-6

I have an object with methods in it. I want one of the methods inmy obj to be able to use data in other nodes of my object;

```
myObj = {
  state : { a:1, b:1},
  addStuff: (x) => {
    return state.a + x
  }
}

myObj.addStuff(3)
```

what are the most elegant ways to do so? One way I know is to use the object name inside of it; `return myObj.state.a + x`
Are there better ways to accomplish the same? I did try both `self` and `this` inside the method but neither worked.

Answer (score 1):

If the fat arrow is not the requirement don't use it.

```js
myObj = {
  state : { a:1, b:1},
  addStuff: function(x) {
    return this.state.a + x
  }
}

myObj.addStuff(3)
```

or

```js
myObj = {
  state : { a:1, b:1},
  addStuff(x) {
    return this.state.a + x
  }
}

console.log(myObj.addStuff(3))
```

Comment: Thanks. I would very much want to use the arrow functions. And I assume thats where my problems stem from.

Comment: @RishavSharan What would be the advantage of using an arrow function in this situation in your opinion? Using a tool for its own sake is never a good idea. Even more so if it's the wrong tool for the task.

Comment: @abetteroliver I have realized that my approach was wrong. arrow functions are not the correct syntax to use here.